# Get the current ViewModel for a UserControl in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm, user-controls, win-universal-app, mvvm-light

I have a `UserControl` which is used on multiple `View`s. Each `View` has its own `ViewModel`. I know I can get the current `ViewModel` for the `UserControl` from its code behind using

```
GamePageViewModel viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GamePageViewModel>();
```

However since the `UserControl` can be associated with any `ViewModel` based on the `View` it's currently on, how do I get the correct `ViewModel` from the `UserControl` code behind?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your UserControl does not have its own viewmodel, but uses the viewmodel from whatever View is hosting the UserControl?

Comment: That is correct. It uses the ViewModel of whatever View hosting it.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the DataContext of your control in code behind. Let´s say you have the instance `MyControl` of type `UserControl`, and you want it´s ViewModel instance `MyControlViewModel` of type `GamePageViewModel`. In this case, you get the instance with

```
GamePageViewModel MyControlViewModel = MyControl.DataContext as GamePageViewModel;
```

Comment: So does that mean if  the current viewmodel is NOT `GamePageViewModel`, `MyControlViewModel` will return null?

Comment: Totally correct, if this is a problem, you should make a class BaseViewModel and derive GamePageViewModel from this BaseViewModel. Then you can cast the DataContext as BaseViewModel ad use it with different derived ViewModels.

Comment: I do have a BaseViewModel but when I cast it to GamePageViewModel it still return NULL. The UserControl's ViewModel is GamePageViewModel.   `BaseViewModel currenVM = this.DataContext as BaseViewModel;

            if ((GamePageViewModel)currenVM != null)               
            {
                viewModel = currenVM as GamePageViewModel;
            }`

Comment: Go on with the currenVM without casting it to a GamePageViewModel if you don´t know which ViewModel you get.

Comment: I need to access properties in the GamePageViewModel which is not available in the BaseViewModel so using currentVM without casting produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access some properties common for all ViewModels that you could use with the `UserControl`, specify an interface (or another base class) and cast the `DataContext` to this interface.

However, usually it's a bad idea to specify the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` directly. If you want to pass some context into the `UserControl`, use a dependency property as described [here](https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/) (see the `Use dependency properties to pass parameters to a view` section)
.

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea  if I can move common properties to the base class. But just wondering how do I get the ViewModel of the View that is hosting the UserControl via code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply interrogate the DataContext of the control itself.  The code will search up the dependency tree until it finds a data context (which should be the hosting page's ViewModel)  Depending on how you design your ViewModels, you can handle it a number of different ways.  Here are a few that may work for you, or may require some redesign on your part.

**These methods were suggested by @Fruchtzwerg and @mechanic. I'm just trying to help clarify.**

It does seem that there would be other options that don't involve interrogating the view model from code behind, but the purpose of your code is not stated.

(all code is in the user control code-behind, as your post suggests)

A bunch of if/then statements (probably least preferred)

```
    if (DataContext is ViewModelA)
    {
        var _vm = (ViewModelA)DataContext;
        _vm.DoViewModelAMethod();
        _vm.Property1 = "abc";
    }
    else if (DataContext is ViewModelB)
    {
        var _vm = (ViewModelB)DataContext;
        _vm.DoViewModelBMethod();
        _vm.Property1 = "abc";
    }
    //etc. etc.
```

Move common methods/properties to a base class (called VMBase here) and inherit your viewmodels from it (and VMBase to inherit from MVVMLight ViewModelBase?)

```
    var _vm = DataContext as VMBase;
    if(_vm != null)
    {
        _vm.DoViewModelMethod();
        _vm.Property1 = "abc";
    }
```

If you are using different implementations of the common methods/properties, use and interface and have the viewmodels implement the interface.

```
    var _vm = DataContext as IVMBase;
    if(_vm != null)
    {
        _vm.DoViewModelMethod();
        _vm.Property1 = "abc";
    }
```